# Putting <> in bean property value?

Tags: java, spring

I just want to know how to correctly put the characters '<' and '>' within the value of a property located within a bean. Eclipse doesn't seem to understand that I am trying to pass those characters as a part of a string value.

Edit: How I would I write escapes for multiple < and > in the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `<` and `>` are valid XML characters, you'll have to escape them:

```
<bean value="&gt;" ... />
<!-- or -->
<bean value="&lt;" ... />
```

Comment: what if I have multiple < and > within the value? Do I have to escape each of them?

Comment: Yup, all of them have to be escaped.

Comment: okay thanks.. that's kind of annoying haha. To use multiple escape sequences would it look something like <bean value="&gt;" "&gt;""&lt;"&gt;"... />?

Comment: still need an answer to this^

Comment: @user2665166, it should be something like `<bean value="&gt;&lt;&gt;&lt;" ... >`

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean  ......>
    <value><![CDATA[ < ]]></value>
</bean>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's original question, a few lines of explanation will help current and future readers understand your question even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of following option:

```
Option 1:
    <bean  ......>
            <value><![CDATA[ < ]]></value>
    </bean>

Option 2: 
    <bean value="&gt;" ... />
    <!-- or -->
    <bean value="&lt;" ... />
```

But I would prefer to use first one.

Comment: could you answer my Edit in the question by chance?